# Admin bar stats widget plugin image broken

Tags: images, admin, statistics

Using Wordpress Stats on my site. On the admin bar when logged in and viewing the site, the spark image with daily stats is broken. It's not a critical issue, just an annoyance. Any ideas?

[image]

Edit:

Broken URL: http://www.denveroffthewagon.com/wp-admin/?page=stats&noheader&proxy&chart=admin-bar-hours&height=20&hours=48

Comment: What is the broken url?

Comment: http://www.denveroffthewagon.com/wp-admin/?page=stats&noheader&proxy&chart=admin-bar-hours&height=20&hours=48

Comment: there seems an image for the link

Comment: @Sean - what do you mean?

Comment: If a broken link, the text will simply appear, but you will probably get some type of 404 or 300 or 500 errors. In your screenshot, it's a broken image. Do you have a page source? Your link above require username and password to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this could be caused by a variety of different issues, here are some general steps to take to try and troubleshoot it.

1. Completely delete the plugin (deactivate and then delete files) and then re-install it. Simple, I know, but often works wonders. Try uploading the plugin files manually as well as installing from within the admin panel using the search to see if either make a difference.
2. Try installing the plugin using the [Jetpack combo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) plugin.
3. Look in the plugin's folder for a `.htaccess` file. If found, rename it to `htaccess` (drop the period) and see if that solves it. If so, your server configuration needs to change slightly.

   1. Rename the file back to `.htaccess` (put the period back)
   2. Add `AllowOverride FileInfo Limit` to the top of the `.htaccess` file
   3. Test again. For more info see here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpresscom-stats-stats-graph-missing-after-update#post-1366537

If none of the above work, then let us know what server and OS you're running, as well as any errors in your PHP and error logs that you may think are relevant.

Comment: If I remove the plugin, will the history of data be lost as well?

Comment: AFAIK, the historical data is all stored on Auttomatic's servers. For example, you should be able to go and log in at wordpress.com and see the stats. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-are-the-stats-stored